# Can I get the value of an Enum from the CodeModel in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, enums, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to get all the metadata from certain classes in our model using the CodeModel in Visual Studio. I've come pretty far already. When the routines discover a property of type enum I would like to be able to get all the enumeration as a result.

When an enum is found I get a CodeEnum object that has a Members property which in turn contains all the enumerations. The names of the Enumerations is available but I don't see the values anywhere. Does anyone know how to get the values for the enumerations from the CodeEnum object?

Answer (score 0):

```
using EnvDTE;

// Given CodeEnum someEnum already set...
foreach (CodeVariable enumItem in someEnum.Members)
{
    // Do something with value in InitExpression...
    object theValue = enumItem.InitExpression;
}
```

Comment: please add some explaination or comments for this answer.

Comment: It has been a while since I asked this question. I'll take a look tomorrow. I think I solved it already but thanks anyway